# Will my 3rd party iOS app automatically send notifications to Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

I'm creating an iOS application for the iPhone the has push notification abilities. If a user has an Apple watch and has notification mirroring on, will the Watch get the notification automatically, or would I need to develop a watch app as well so that they can pop up on it? The latter seems to make more sense based off of other notification models, but the way Apple talks about the notification functionality being automatic in their docs is throwing me off a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watch will show a push notification even if you don't have a watch app, but you will get the  default design and functionality.

Comment: Are there some additional settings or configurations that need to be made during the development process to support that?

Comment: No , if your app on the iPhone can get push notifications then the watch will be able to get them . Of course the watchOS decides when is the appropriate time to show it and your phone need to be locked ...